# Cannot read property 'geocode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var loca = new google.maps.LatLng(41.7475, -74.0872);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: loca,
    zoom: 8
  });

}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      var request = {
        location: results[0].geometry.location,
        radius: 50000,
        name: 'ski',
        keyword: 'mountain',
        type: ['park']
      };
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My application currently finds the nearest ski areas, based on the latitude and longitude that is hardcoded in. I would like to be able to type in an address and convert that address into the latitude and longitude for the search. I am using Google Maps api and the places library. I know that I somehow need to use geocoding but not sure how to do that. Here is the code:

Comment: instead of `var geocoder` on first line, directly use `var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

Comment: On which line are you getting the undefined geocoder error?

Comment: `geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  },` this line i getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has no error, it is working fine for me, check the below example.

The problem may be:

1)your `places-api` script may be wrong.
2)Your `codeAddress()` is being called before script loads. **Make sure the script loads first**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var loca = new google.maps.LatLng(41.7475, -74.0872);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: loca,
    zoom: 8
  });

}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      var request = {
        location: results[0].geometry.location,
        radius: 50000,
        name: 'ski',
        keyword: 'mountain',
        type: ['park']
      };
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<title>Google Maps API v3 Example : Geocoding Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>


<div align="center" style="height: 30px; width: 530px">
<input id="address" type="textbox">
<input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
<div id="map" style="height:200px; width: 530px"></div>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y1eet8r6/)

Comment: where i place this script header or footer ?

Comment: place it in the first line in head tag